# como inicializar el constructor un array generico ejemplo T

Tags: java

```
public class StackArrays<T> implements MyStack<T> {
    private Object[] stack;
    private int posicion;

    public StackArrays(int tam){ //no me anda
        T stack1= new [tam];
        this.stack = stack1;
        this.posicion = 0;
    }

    public void pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (this.stack[posicion] == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        stack[posicion] = null;
        posicion = posicion - 1;

    }

    public T top() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (stack[posicion] == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        return stack[posicion];
    }

    public void push(T element) {
        posicion = posicion + 1;
        stack[posicion] = element;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (stack[posicion] == null) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void makeEmpty() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= posicion; i++) {
            stack[i] = null;
        }
        posicion = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes inicializar un array de tipo genérico usando `new`. Necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

```
public class StackArrays<T> implements MyStack<T> {
    private T[] stack;
    private int posicion;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public StackArrays(Class<T> cl, int tam){
        T [] stack1= (T[]) Array.newInstance(cl, tam);
        this.stack = stack1;
        this.posicion = 0;
    }

    // ... resto de métodos sin cambios
}
```

Como ves, ademas es necesario pasar la clase del genérico para que Array sepa exactamente qué tipo de elemento está creando, y aún así necesitas hacer un *casting* para asignarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta un constructor porque el array se inicializa en el constructor sin parámetros pero entre los nombres raros y que no me pones todas las clases que tienes creadas ni me explicas mas sobre el ejercicio no te puedo ser de mas ayuda